# Is there a way in the hy language to use doto on self?

Tags: hy

hopefully someone can help me with this hy question.  I am porting some python code over to hy, and was trying to figure out how I could remove some repetitive code using the doto macro.  For example, look at a python class like this:

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.z = z
```

How could I convert this in hy to use doto?

```
(defclass Foo [object]
  [[__init__ (fn [self x y z]
               (doto self  ;
                 (setv ...) ; What goes here? 
  ))]])
```

The problem is that it looks like you normally do something like this:

```
(defclass Foo [object]
  [[__init__ (fn [self x y z]
               (setv self.x x)
               (setv self.y y)
               (setv self.z z))]])
```

I don't see a way of using (doto) on self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an interesting idea. You can do this:

```
(doto self
  (setattr "x" x)
  (setattr "y" y)
  (setattr "z" z))
```

But it's not much better. Consider defining a macro:

```
(defmacro vars-to-attrs [obj &rest attrs]
  (let [[actions (list (map
                        (fn (a) `(setattr (str '~a) ~a))
                        attrs))]]
    `(doto ~obj ~@actions)))
```

And then calling it like this:

```
(vars-to-attrs self x y z)
```

This might work better as a function though:

```
(defun vars-to-attrs-fun [obj &rest attrs]
  (for [a attrs]
    (setattr obj a (get (locals) a))))
```

And then call it like:

```
(vars-to-attrs-fun self 'x 'y 'z)
```

or, equivalent:

```
(vars-to-attrs-fun self "x" "y" "z")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep `__init__`'s locals, the easiest way is to directly `.update` the instance vars with the local vars.

```
(defclass Foo [object]
   (defn __init__ [self x y z]
     (.update (vars self) (vars))))
```

(By the way, the above is using our new `defclass` syntax from the version of Hy on Github, which won't work with the current PyPI version. [Update: it's now in the current PyPI release])

This does include *all* the locals, so you get a `self.self`, which is probably harmless, but you can `del` it after if you want. Hy sometimes generates locals to make statements act like expressions. These could also end up in the instance dict if you're not careful. You can avoid this by `assoc`ing only the names you want:

```
(assoc (vars self)
  'x x
  'y y
  'z z))
```

The new `setv` syntax also takes an arbitrary number of pairs, so you could do something like this instead:

```
;; new setv syntax
(setv self.x x
      self.y y
      self.z z)
```

You could pretty much do this before using tuples:

```
;; works in both Hy versions
(setv (, self.x self.y self.z)
      (, x y z))
```

You can also avoid duplication in `.update` with a `dict-comp`, though this isn't usually shorter.

```
(.update (vars self) (dict-comp k (get (vars) k) [k '[x y z]]))
```

If you're still set on using `doto`, the correct syntax is:

```
(doto self
    (-> (. x) (setv x))
    (-> (. y) (setv y))
    (-> (. z) (setv z)))
```

This does avoid repeating `self`, but it's not shorter than the aforementioned alternatives, so `doto` is the wrong tool for this particular job.

---

#### Update

I've made an issue for this https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/1532

We might be adding an `attach` macro to Hy. I also posted an [implementation](https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/1532#issuecomment-385301571) if you want to try it out early.

Usage:

```
(defclass Foo []
  (defn __init__[self x y z]
    (attach self x y z)))
```

Since the attachment target is the first argument, `attach` would also work in a `->` or in a `doto`, e.g.

```
(doto self
  (.configure foo bar)
  (attach spam eggs))
```